# how to parse json to c# and read values

Tags: c#, json, web-services, parsing, console-application

Alright i need to parse JSON to c#, from online webservice. This is my first time parsing JSON, and im not really any good in console applications yet, so i really need your help.

After i parse JSON, i need to create app which will respond with "Turn off" if temperature degrees reaches some random value (lets say 150degrees).

This is my code so far...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        var data = webClient.DownloadString("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/135/feed.json");
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
        Console.WriteLine("Channel: " + o["channel"]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is what i get displayed.

[image]

i have no idea if i did this right, but i do get some data displayed. any idea on how to continue?

**Thank you!**

Comment: Does that API have any documentation? Find out the method and parameters it's expecting. You can start playing around with Fiddler before building the applicaton

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy can you please check link to api?

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here. You've already used JObject the way that it's intended in the `o["channel"]` call. `o["channel"]` returns another JObject so just use that one the same way. For example, you could write `o["channel"]["id"]` to get the ID. Or you could capture the value of `o["channel"]` to a variable and then use `otherVariable["id"]`. You could also create JSON-serializable objects so that you can deserialize the JSON to a strongly-typed C# object.

Comment: The API is documented here -- http://www.newtonsoft.com/json . Don't ask us to read it for you.

Comment: Note that the data coming back also has a "feeds" value that you could use to get the temperature readings and then add some logic where "if temp > warning_value then do warning" where what I have in quotes is more like pseudo code than anything else.

Comment: @JBKing how on earth did u see "feeds". i've tried it but it doesnt return any temperature, unless "field" is suppose to be temperature?

Comment: Not "field" but "field1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I go to http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/135/feed.json , this is the result I get :

> {"channel":{"id":135,"name":"Thermometer","description":"Wireless
>   outdoor thermometer (Electric Imp, TI TMP102 sensor, 4 x AA Energizer
>   L91).","latitude":"55.652072","longitude":"12.546301","field1":"Temperature","created_at":"2011-02-23T22:43:37Z","updated_at":"2015-10-19T22:40:08Z","elevation":"20m","last_entry_id":61335},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2015-10-18T22:50:09Z","entry_id":61240,"field1":"6.8125"},{"created_at":"2015-10-18T23:05:17Z","entry_id":61241,"field1":"6.75"},

....

> {"created_at":"2015-10-19T21:55:03Z","entry_id":61332,"field1":"9.875"},{"created_at":"2015-10-19T22:10:04Z","entry_id":61333,"field1":"9.875"},{"created_at":"2015-10-19T22:25:06Z","entry_id":61334,"field1":"9.875"},{"created_at":"2015-10-19T22:40:08Z","entry_id":61335,"field1":"9.875"}]}

Where the middle are the other values. The `"Feeds"` part is the array where `"field1"` is the temperature as the `"channel"` is kind of like a legend here. There are entries that are timestamped, given an ID and then a value which I'd presume is the temperature.

Thus, you have to convert the last entry of `Feeds` and then you'll have the most recent temperature where you still have to wrap this in a timer so that it repeats getting the latest reading and add the logic to send off an alert in whatever form you want here.